# Get previous number in loop when saved to variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops, datetime

still new to learning JavaScript. I want to loop through some values. If value is greater or equal to a certain number, then break the loop and get the previous number. For example:

```js
var time = [14, 35];
var interval = 40; // in minutes
var startTime = [10, 40];

var timeFormatted = '2019-02-04 '+time[0]+':'+time[1];
var startTimeFormatted = '2019-02-04 '+startTime[0]+':'+startTime[1];

var dtTime = new Date(timeFormatted);
var dtStartTime = new Date(startTimeFormatted);

var currentTime = dtStartTime;
for(i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    var previouslySelectedTime = currentTime;
    currentTime.setMinutes(currentTime.getMinutes() + interval);
    currentTime = new Date(currentTime);
    if(currentTime >= dtTime) {
        break;
    }
}

alert(previouslySelectedTime);
```

The final time result of `beforeTime` should be `14:00:00` but it is showing `14:40:00`. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at `currentTime`, it is referencing a [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object. So, when you execute the next code:

```
var previouslySelectedTime = currentTime;
```

the variable `previouslySelectedTime` will reference the same object that is referenced by `currentTime`. Then later you execute:

```
currentTime.setMinutes(currentTime.getMinutes() + interval);
```

that will change the object referenced by both, `currentTime` and `previouslySelectedTime`. The easy fix to this will be to create a new `Date` from `currentTime` before assigning it to the mentioned variable:

```
var previouslySelectedTime = new Date(currentTime);
```

Also, after fixing this, there is no need of the next line:

```
currentTime = new Date(currentTime);
```

**Example**

```js
var time = [14, 35];
var interval = 40; // in minutes
var startTime = [10, 40];

var timeFormatted = '2019-02-04 ' + time[0] + ':' + time[1];
var startTimeFormatted = '2019-02-04 ' + startTime[0] + ':' + startTime[1];

var dtTime = new Date(timeFormatted);
var currentTime = new Date(startTimeFormatted);
var previouslySelectedTime;

for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    previouslySelectedTime = new Date(currentTime);
    currentTime.setMinutes(currentTime.getMinutes() + interval);

    if (currentTime >= dtTime)
        break;
}

alert(previouslySelectedTime);
```

**Simplified version:**

Even more, you could make some simplifications in your code if you use the methods that `Date()` object provides and a `while` loop.

```js
var time = [14, 35];
var interval = 40; // in minutes
var startTime = [10, 40];

var dtTime = new Date();
dtTime.setHours(time[0], time[1], 0);
var currentTime = new Date();
currentTime.setHours(startTime[0], startTime[1], 0);
var previouslySelectedTime;

while (currentTime < dtTime)
{
    previouslySelectedTime = new Date(currentTime);
    currentTime.setMinutes(currentTime.getMinutes() + interval);    
}

alert(previouslySelectedTime);
```

Comment: I'd like to know why someone -1 to this answer, especially if this works

Answer (score 4):

you can use do while for this purpose

where the loop iterate at least once before the condition is evaluated, if true continue else break.

```
var time = [14, 35];
var interval = 40; // in minutes
var startTime = [10, 40];

var timeFormatted = '2019-02-04 '+time[0]+':'+time[1];
var startTimeFormatted = '2019-02-04 '+startTime[0]+':'+startTime[1];

var dtTime = new Date(timeFormatted);
var dtStartTime = new Date(startTimeFormatted);

var currentTime = dtStartTime;
var previouslySelectedTime = null;
do {
    var previouslySelectedTime = currentTime;
    currentTime.setMinutes(currentTime.getMinutes() + interval);
    currentTime = new Date(currentTime);

} while (!(currentTime < dtTime));

alert(previouslySelectedTime);
```

Answer (score 2):

**A small change can solve your problem.**

```
var previouslySelectedTime = new Date(currentTime);//line no : 10
```

**Reason:**

here javascript is copy reference only. That's why, when currentTime change then previouslySelectedTime also change.

**Solution:**

You should apply **Deep copy** here.

https://medium.com/@Farzad_YZ/3-ways-to-clone-objects-in-javascript-f752d148054d

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a reference by the following line

```
var previouslySelectedTime = currentTime;
```

So after this when you setMinutes on `currentTime` it also changes `previouslySelectedTime`

.You need to copy the value of `currentTime` and then assign it to `previouslySelectedTime` using `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify())`

```js
var time = [14, 35];
var interval = 40; // in minutes
var startTime = [10, 40];

var timeFormatted = '2019-02-04 '+time[0]+':'+time[1];
var startTimeFormatted = '2019-02-04 '+startTime[0]+':'+startTime[1];

var dtTime = new Date(timeFormatted);
var dtStartTime = new Date(startTimeFormatted);

var currentTime = dtStartTime;
var previouslySelectedTime;

for(let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    previouslySelectedTime = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(currentTime));
    currentTime.setMinutes(currentTime.getMinutes() + interval);
    currentTime = new Date(currentTime);
    if(currentTime >= dtTime) {
        break;
    }
    
}

console.log(previouslySelectedTime);
```

Comment: I did not downvote. I selected the other answer as best answer because it used `new Date()` which I already had instead of JSON which is a bit confusing to me

Comment: @pixie123 Np `new Date()` is a better option

Comment: @pixie123 You should also take care of two other things. You should declare `previouslySelectedTime` outside of for loop and change it inside loop. And also use `let` for declaration of `i` inside loop.